# How to import a iOS library after adding it to expo project?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, react-native-native-module

I have an expo project, and I added the iOS library named "OPPWAMobile.xcframework" from xcode (added it to Frameworks)
I have a local native module in the path "modules/oppwa" inside that module I have the following `OPPWA-Briding-Header.h` file:

```c
#include <OPPWAMobile/OPPWAMobile.h>
```

I added the briding header to allow me to import the library in swift files.

My project directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── ios
│   ├── MyProject  // my project's auto generated
│   ├── ipworks3ds_sdk.xcframework  // I added this as part of the library
│   ├── OPPWAMobile.xcframework  // this is the library that I need to import
├── modules
│   └── oppwa  // my custom native module
│       ├── expo-module.config.json
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── ios
│       │   ├── Oppwa.podspec
│       │   └── src
│       │       ├── OPPWA-Bridging-Header.h  // the briding header file
│       │       ├── OppwaModule.swift  // my custom swift code that needs to import OPPWAMobile
│       └── src
│           ├── OppwaModule.ts
```

I get an error that the OPPWAMobile.h header file is not found!